# SQL Insert statement, does not use a $variable's value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a variable named `$src`, that does have a value, (I checked it before the insert). But when I execute the insert statement, the field is saved as blank "";

I don't know what the problem is, I have a text field in my DB set to accept any kind of character... and still it did not work.

Someone help me please.

```
<?php

include 'fimg.class.php';
require('cone.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$tipo_bolsa = $_POST['tipo_bolsa'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$imagen = $_POST['imagen'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$sueldo = $_POST['sueldo'];
$idP = $_POST['idP'];

$src = "";

if (isset($_FILES["file"])) 
{
    $file = $_FILES["file"];
    $nombre = FIMG::getUniqueName();
    $tipo = $file["type"];
    $ruta_provisional = $file["tmp_name"];
    $size = $file["size"];
    $carpeta = "upload/";
    $src = $carpeta.$nombre;
    move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);
    $img = new FIMG($src);
    $img->setWidth(500);
    $img->save(null,FJPG);
    $img->close();
    echo "<img src='$src'>";
}
    echo $src;

     $con = Conectar();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO bolsa (id, tipo_bolsa, titulo, imagen, descripcion, categoria, fecha, sueldo) VALUES (:id, :tipo_bolsa, :titulo, '$src', :descripcion, :categoria, :fecha, :sueldo)";
    echo "<br>".$sql; //Checkpoint

    //Variable $src does have a value i check it (img_9uf87d8fwhatever7asd7f89adsf.jpg) but when i do the insert the field inserted is empty ""

     $q = $con->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':tipo_bolsa'=>$tipo_bolsa, ':titulo'=>$titulo, ':descripcion'=>$descripcion, ':categoria'=>$categoria, ':fecha'=>$fecha, ':sueldo'=>$sueldo));


?>
```

This is what i get when i print the sentence, before send:

```
INSERT INTO bolsa (id, tipo_bolsa, titulo, imagen, descripcion, categoria, fecha, sueldo) VALUES (:id, :tipo_bolsa, :titulo, 'upload/img_20160108154835d45f49a8db1d6f1f4d2e29.jpg', :descripcion, :categoria, :fecha, :sueldo)
```

[And this is my db info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXpze.png)

Comment: What is that column set as?

Comment: In the database is type text, the variable has the name of an image (img_sdfasjdfjkfjafsdfasdfa.jpg) i print it before insert like i show, but when the sentences ejecutes the field is empty, all the fields take the value but this

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO bolsa (id, tipo_bolsa, titulo, imagen, descripcion, categoria, fecha, sueldo) VALUES (:id, :tipo_bolsa, :titulo, '$src', :descripcion, :categoria, :fecha, :sueldo)";

 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':tipo_bolsa'=>$tipo_bolsa, ':titulo'=>$titulo, ':descripcion'=>$descripcion, ':categoria'=>$categoria, ':fecha'=>$fecha, ':sueldo'=>$sueldo));
```

Why are you treating $src differently from the rest?  That is, why not:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO bolsa (id, tipo_bolsa, titulo, imagen, descripcion, categoria, fecha, sueldo) VALUES (:id, :tipo_bolsa, :titulo, :src, :descripcion, :categoria, :fecha, :sueldo)";

 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':tipo_bolsa'=>$tipo_bolsa, ':titulo'=>$titulo, ':src'=>$src, ':descripcion'=>$descripcion, ':categoria'=>$categoria, ':fecha'=>$fecha, ':sueldo'=>$sueldo));
```

Comment: Yes because this code i try it before and still kepping the field imagen in blank "". I just try it again and not working

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the schema for that table please

Comment: yes, i update my post with the print sentences before send or ejecute